# Why does substring with starting position zero does not throw error in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, xampp

I ran the query:
SELECT SUBSTRING(first_name,2,3) FROM customers; If 'first_name' is David it will return 'avi'

Similarly, when I tried:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(first_name,0,3) FROM customers;
```

It returns null. Refer to the below drive link.

[image: screenshot of doubt]

Comment: Sorry, no one will click to linked images. Please try to explain your problem in few sentences - this way you can sometimes even find solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
select substring(first_name,1,3) from customers;
```

This should work as the function here in xampp regards 1 as the starting character and not 0.

Comment: if it doesn't start with zero then why it is not throwing an error saying the message to use from one and not zero?

Comment: The position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1. If its 0, it won'tthrow number but just return as null.It'sprobably how this function is defined in Mysql.

Comment: yes, If len is less than 1, the result will be the empty string. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring